# Spacemacs org-mode python session plotting problem

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, python

I have been using `org-mode` with R in Spacemacs for a while now with no issue.

I'm moving my workflow from R to Python.

Jupyter notebooks (EIN) works great, but I prefer `org-mode`:

Normal (non-plot) blocks work well enough, but Emacs hangs when I try to plot using sessions (I can get it to plot if I don't use sessions).

I get a message that says, `executing Python code block...` that remains until I escape with `C-g`.

Here is an example of a function that won't print:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session *Python*
import glob
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
import seaborn as sns
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15, 10)
sns.set()
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python :session *Python* :results output drawer
units.pivot_table('A', 'B', 'C', aggfunc=len).fillna(0).plot()
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.savefig('test.png')
'test.png'
#+END_SRC
```

I really want to use `org-mode` instead of notebooks.  Any idea what I need to correct to make it work?

Comment: Just read from the document that `org-mode` support `matplotlib`, not sure whether it supports `seaborn`, did you used `seaborn` ever in Python? Try to use by myself, did not test yet. https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html

Comment: Have you tried [emacs-jupyter](https://github.com/emacs-jupyter/jupyter)?

Answer (score 0):

Try usimng ipython blocks instead of python (`#+BEGIN_SRC ipython`) and add the following line to your first source block:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Note - I'm not sure if this will work with Spacemacs, but it is what scimax is all about.  I used Spacemacs for about 6 months for python and jupyter notebooks before I switched to scimax for org-mode and never looked back.